# How To Solve .gradle/wrapper not found

Tags: java, php, android, gradle

How to set path Gradle Wrapper?
I want to build apk from web. but i got stack for 2 days to solve this tings.

here my structure folder

```
    /var/www/html/engine/api/application/android_app/WebGenerator/ :
    /.gradle
    /.idea
    /source (path i want to build
    /build
    /gradle
    .gitignore    
    webGenerator.iml
    build.gradle
    gradle.properties
    gradlew
    local.properties
    settings.gradle
```

in my PHP code i put this one to exec gradlew

```
$app_path = '/var/www/html/engine/api/application/android_app/WebGenerator/';

exec($app_path.'gradlew assembleDebug --parallel --offline 2>&1', $outputs));
```

ERROR :

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.4-all/3i2gobhdl0fm2tosnn15g540i0/gradle-2.4-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I think I saw some related post somewhere in stack.
It seems that the server cannot find /.gradle
please check stack for older post.

Comment: where? can you share to me

Answer (score 0):

The path is incorrect... This is how the project structure should look the below.  Also the wrapper script shown in your project structure `gradleW` not `gradlew`... note the uppercase `W` instead of lowercase `w`.  Could have been a typo but if not that could also cause a problem depending on your OS.

[image: project structure with wrapper]

Then you can execute the gradle wrapper by `./gradlew clean build` from the root directory of the project.

If you need to generate the wrapper scripts then from the project root (where the `build.gradle/settings.gradle` files are) just execute `gradle wrapper` which will generate the all the needed `wrapper` files.

Comment: thanks it could be my typo actually. 
back to my question. how to build project in app directory?
i put 

`include ':app' `

in my settings.gradle

Comment: can you build it using gradle without the PHP script?

Comment: `gradle build` would be the most obvious way to build the product, but preferably you would use the same command your PHP script is using to trigger the build